# Converting number to format with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

How can I convert number like 4273095782 to number 4 273 095 782 with NSNumberFormatter?

I use this diode but not get it

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 3;
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3;
formatter.groupingSeparator = @" ";
formatter.decimalSeparator = @" ";
NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:p];
```

Comment: With `formatter.groupingSeparator = @" ";[formatter setGroupingSize:3];`, it should do the trick.

Comment: Comment out the integer-digit limit... This will do it :)

Comment: @Larme: no that alone will not do... he need to use `setSecondaryGroupingSize:3` too. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two properties : `setGroupingSize:` for last 3 digits and `setSecondaryGroupingSize:` for all other digits:

The complete implementation will go like this:

```
NSInteger integer = 4273095782;
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@" "];
NSString * threeSeparated =  [formatter stringFromNumber:@(integer)];
NSLog(@"threeSeparated: %@", threeSeparated);
```

**Output: 4 273 095 782**

Answer (score 0):

Try this little manipulation:

```
NSNumber *p = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123456789];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
//     formatter.maximumIntegerDigits = 10;
//     formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3;
formatter.groupingSeparator = @" ";
formatter.decimalSeparator = @" ";
NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:p];

NSLog(@"Formatted:%@", formattedNumber);
```

Hope this helps you. You don't need to limit the integer digits in this case :)

Result should be: `2014-11-27 11:49:39.855 NSNumberFormatter[2399:789883] Formatted:123 456 789`

Comment: the output you showed doesn't happen to come in my Xcode6

Comment: @AnoopVaidya using a long for this huge number would work with my code too.